how to scraping All airbnb search results that is limited to 15 pages
To scrape airbnb.com I have a big problem.
This is my code(python):
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.airbnb.com/s/Italy/homes?tab_id=home_tab&refinement_paths%5B%5D=%2Fhomes&flexible_trip_lengths%5B%5D=one_week&monthly_start_date=2024-05-01&monthly_length=3&monthly_end_date=2024-08-01&price_filter_input_type=0&channel=EXPLORE&date_picker_type=calendar&checkin=2024-05-16&checkout=2024-05-17&adults=1&source=structured_search_input_header&search_type=user_map_move&price_filter_num_nights=1&zoom=5.703720341646269&zoom_level=5.703720341646269&query=Italy&place_id=ChIJA9KNRIL-1BIRb15jJFz1LOI&ne_lat=46.12096643813858&ne_lng=27.19562831030737&sw_lat=37.79321931924548&sw_lng=-0.4337798647522675&search_by_map=true")
page_load_time=5
driver.maximize_window()
time.sleep(30)
NextPage_Xpath='//*[@aria-label="Next"]'
nextpage_elements=driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,NextPage_Xpath)
if(len(nextpage_elements)>0):
    while True:
        next_perfomation=WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(
                EC.element_to_be_clickable(nextpage_elements[0]))
        if(next_perfomation):
            next_perfomation.click()
            time.sleep(10)
        else:
            break

the results are over 1000 but result pages that is shown are limited to 15 pages.
resluts pagination Image
to solve this problem, I checked pages URL and I found a hashed value specified by cursor variable and decoded it.for example, the URL of Page 2, has this hashed key :
eyJzZWN0aW9uX29mZnNldCI6MSwiaXRlbXNfb2Zmc2V0IjozNiwidmVyc2lvbiI6MX0%3D

and its decoded value is :
{"section_offset":1,"items_offset":36,"version":1}7

but i could not find a way to handle this issue.
Now, How can I load/see all search results(more than 15 pages).
Update:
I checked response ajax data when clicked on a page . in response there are hashed values for pagination.
"paginationInfo": {
            "__typename": "StaysSearchPaginationInfo",
            "pageCursors": [
              "eyJzZWN0aW9uX29mZnNldCI6MCwiaXRlbXNfb2Zmc2V0IjowLCJ2ZXJzaW9uIjoxfQ==",
              "eyJzZWN0aW9uX29mZnNldCI6MiwiaXRlbXNfb2Zmc2V0IjoxOCwidmVyc2lvbiI6MX0=",
              "eyJzZWN0aW9uX29mZnNldCI6MiwiaXRlbXNfb2Zmc2V0IjozNiwidmVyc2lvbiI6MX0=",
              "eyJzZWN0aW9uX29mZnNldCI6MiwiaXRlbXNfb2Zmc2V0Ijo1NCwidmVyc2lvbiI6MX0=",
              "eyJzZWN0aW9uX29mZnNldCI6MiwiaXRlbXNfb2Zmc2V0Ijo3MiwidmVyc2lvbiI6MX0=",
              "eyJzZWN0aW9uX29mZnNldCI6MiwiaXRlbXNfb2Zmc2V0Ijo5MCwidmVyc2lvbiI6MX0=",
              "eyJzZWN0aW9uX29mZnNldCI6MiwiaXRlbXNfb2Zmc2V0IjoxMDgsInZlcnNpb24iOjF9",
              "eyJzZWN0aW9uX29mZnNldCI6MiwiaXRlbXNfb2Zmc2V0IjoxMjYsInZlcnNpb24iOjF9",
              "eyJzZWN0aW9uX29mZnNldCI6MiwiaXRlbXNfb2Zmc2V0IjoxNDQsInZlcnNpb24iOjF9",
              "eyJzZWN0aW9uX29mZnNldCI6MiwiaXRlbXNfb2Zmc2V0IjoxNjIsInZlcnNpb24iOjF9",
              "eyJzZWN0aW9uX29mZnNldCI6MiwiaXRlbXNfb2Zmc2V0IjoxODAsInZlcnNpb24iOjF9",
              "eyJzZWN0aW9uX29mZnNldCI6MiwiaXRlbXNfb2Zmc2V0IjoxOTgsInZlcnNpb24iOjF9",
              "eyJzZWN0aW9uX29mZnNldCI6MiwiaXRlbXNfb2Zmc2V0IjoyMTYsInZlcnNpb24iOjF9",
              "eyJzZWN0aW9uX29mZnNldCI6MiwiaXRlbXNfb2Zmc2V0IjoyMzQsInZlcnNpb24iOjF9",
              "eyJzZWN0aW9uX29mZnNldCI6MiwiaXRlbXNfb2Zmc2V0IjoyNTIsInZlcnNpb24iOjF9",
              "eyJzZWN0aW9uX29mZnNldCI6MiwiaXRlbXNfb2Zmc2V0IjoyNzAsInZlcnNpb24iOjF9",
              "eyJzZWN0aW9uX29mZnNldCI6MiwiaXRlbXNfb2Zmc2V0IjoyODgsInZlcnNpb24iOjF9"
            ],
            "previousPageCursor": "eyJzZWN0aW9uX29mZnNldCI6MCwiaXRlbXNfb2Zmc2V0IjowLCJ2ZXJzaW9uIjoxfQ==",
            "nextPageCursor": "eyJzZWN0aW9uX29mZnNldCI6MiwiaXRlbXNfb2Zmc2V0IjozNiwidmVyc2lvbiI6MX0="
          },


yeah, it is limited .... did you eve find solution?
